# Can't login on chat.SE, stackauth times out

Tags: bug, chat, login

Since about an hour I can't login to chat.SE server. Other login services seems to be working (I could login in SE and SO) but chat.SE seems to be unaware of this.

Here traceroute:

```
Start: Sat May 31 15:01:39 2014
HOST: bt                          Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  7.|-- he-0-12-0-0-cr01.56mariet  0.0%    10   50.8  52.5  49.8  56.7   1.8
  8.|-- he-1-9-0-0-cr01.dallas.tx  0.0%    10   82.5  76.7  73.2  82.5   2.3
  9.|-- he-0-8-0-0-cr01.losangele  0.0%    10  101.2 102.2  97.8 129.8   9.7
 10.|-- he-2-13-0-0-cr01.sanjose.  0.0%    10  110.6 114.5 109.5 141.9   9.7
 11.|-- 68.86.95.118               0.0%    10  119.3 120.5 119.0 128.2   2.7
 12.|-- ae-0-0-ar03.troutdale.or.  0.0%    10  120.4 121.7 117.6 145.1   8.3
 13.|-- ae-50-0-sur04.corvallis.o  0.0%    10  122.3 122.1 121.0 126.1   1.3
 14.|-- 50-200-51-238-static.hfc.  0.0%    10  123.3 122.9 121.8 123.7   0.0
 15.|-- ge-1-0-2.cvo-core-r2.peak  0.0%    10  122.4 122.5 120.7 125.7   1.4
 16.|-- 69.59.218.150              0.0%    10  123.4 126.8 123.4 137.4   5.3
 17.|-- cs.peakgamers.com         10.0%    10  124.0 123.3 122.1 124.0   0.0
 18.|-- 69.59.197.21              10.0%    10  124.1 121.5 119.8 124.1   1.1
```

Here is the url that stall in answering `https://stackauth.com/auth/global/read`

Comment: This might be related to https://twitter.com/stackstatus/status/472829578994794496. FWIW, I can't even log into *any* SE site at the moment (on a device where I haven't got a current session).

Comment: @Braiam: Because I thought it was a different tweet. Oops.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed], correct?